# How do kmer counters determine which kmer is 'canonical'?

Tags: k-mer

When counting canonical kmers, ie kmers in which both the forward and reverse complement of a sequence are treated as identical, how do kmer counting programs decide which kmer to use as the canonical sequence? Do they all work the same way?

To investigate I made a string with `GAGTGCGGAATACCACTCTT` which contains all 16 possible 2mers. I then used [kmc](https://github.com/refresh-bio/KMC) to figure out how they determine which kmer is used. Only the kmers in the `filtered` column below appeared. So, it looks like KMCs' 'canonical' kmers are the ones that first occur alphabetically.

```
╔════════════════╦═════╦════════════════════╦══════════╗
║ Possible Kmers ║ RCs ║ RC occurs earlier? ║ filtered ║
╠════════════════╬═════╬════════════════════╬══════════╣
║ TT             ║ AA  ║ YES                ║ TA       ║
║ TG             ║ CA  ║ YES                ║ GC       ║
║ TC             ║ GA  ║ YES                ║ GA       ║
║ TA             ║ TA  ║                    ║ CG       ║
║ GT             ║ AC  ║ YES                ║ CC       ║
║ GG             ║ CC  ║ YES                ║ CA       ║
║ GC             ║ GC  ║                    ║ AT       ║
║ GA             ║ TC  ║                    ║ AG       ║
║ CT             ║ AG  ║ YES                ║ AC       ║
║ CG             ║ CG  ║                    ║ AA       ║
║ CC             ║ GG  ║                    ║          ║
║ CA             ║ TG  ║                    ║          ║
║ AT             ║ AT  ║                    ║          ║
║ AG             ║ CT  ║                    ║          ║
║ AC             ║ GT  ║                    ║          ║
║ AA             ║ TT  ║                    ║          ║
╚════════════════╩═════╩════════════════════╩══════════╝
```

Do all kmer counting programs use the same canonical kmers, and if so do you have documentation explaining this? I wasn't able to find anything in the papers for `jellyfish` or `kmc`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When a k-mer is identical to its reverse complement, both are canonical. Note that a canonical k-mer is a sequence, irrelevant to its position(s) in the input string. More precisely, give a string $s$, its *canonical string* is
$$
{\rm canonical}(s|h)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
s & \mbox{if $h(s)<h(\overline{s})$}\\
\overline{s} & \mbox{otherwise}\\
\end{array}\right.
$$
where $\overline{s}$ is the Watson-Crick reverse complement of $s$ and $h$ is an arbitrary string hash function. In practice, we most often use 2-bit encoding as $h$. Order under such a hash function is equivalent to the lexicographical order.

Comment: Stated differently, each program can have different canonical k-mers given the same input.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. My less jargon-y translation is: "Kmer counting programs store kmers using a hash, not a string. The hash function produces the same value for a kmer and its Watson-Crick reverse complement. When the kmer counting program prints the counts in human-readable format, it translates the kmer's hash value to a string. Whether one string representation of a kmer or its reverse complement is reported depends on the program-defined "alphabetical order." In the case of KMC, that "alphabetical order" is {ACGT}. This explains why the kmers observed above were reported.